# Draw a circle with rectangles python turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I wanna draw (this shape) polygon with knowing rectangle length and width, and number of rectangles,

[image]

And Here's my code:

```
from turtle import *

color('black')
begin_fill()
length = 50
width = 20
num_of_rectangles = 8
for i in range(num_of_rectangles):
    forward(length)
    right(90)
    forward(width)
    right(90)
    forward(length)
    right(90)
    forward(width)
    right(90)
    penup()
    circle(50, 180/num_of_rectangles, 4)
    pendown()

done()
```

But this code doesn't display the wanted shape, So how can i draw the shape above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rectangles have the right orientation, but the wrong position.  My solution is to have each loop start and end in the centre of the image.    This ensures the rectangles are all at the centre.

```py
from turtle import *

color('black')
begin_fill()
length = 50
width = 20
num_of_rectangles = 8
for i in range(num_of_rectangles):
    # go to corner:
    penup()
    forward(length/2)
    right(90)
    forward(width/2)
    right(90)
    pendown()
    # draw rectangle:
    forward(length)
    right(90)
    forward(width)
    right(90)
    forward(length)
    right(90)
    forward(width)
    right(90)
    penup()
    # go back to centre:
    penup()
    forward(length/2)
    right(90)
    forward(width/2)
    left(90)
    pendown()
    # turn
    right(180/num_of_rectangles)

done()
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of drawing the rectangles as 4 strokes, you can draw it as 5, starting and finishing in the middle of one of the sides. You also need to get to the middle of that side with the pen up, then back to the center (again with the pen up):

```
from turtle import *

color('black')
begin_fill()
length = 50
width = 20
num_of_rectangles = 8
penup()
for i in range(num_of_rectangles):
    # Get to middle of side and orient for drawing
    forward(width / 2)
    right(90)
    pendown()
    # Draw rectangle in 5 strokes
    forward(length / 2)
    right(90)
    forward(width)
    right(90)
    forward(length)
    right(90)
    forward(width)
    right(90)
    forward(length / 2)
    penup()
    # Reorient and get back to center
    left(90)
    backward(width / 2)
    right(180/num_of_rectangles)

done()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong number of rectangles (you only need 6, not 8) and the wrong aspect ratio for your rectangles.  (It's closer to 50x32 than 50x20.) Some of the other proposed solutions inherit these same errors, use too much code to solve the problem, and don't look like the provided image:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 200, 130
RADIUS = 120
PEN_WIDTH = 8

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.width(PEN_WIDTH)

for _ in range(6):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.circle(RADIUS, extent=30)
    turtle.pendown()

    turtle.left(57)

    for _ in range(2):
        turtle.forward(WIDTH)
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(HEIGHT)
        turtle.left(90)

    turtle.right(57)

screen = Screen()
screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

To change the size of the image, multiply or divide the `WIDTH`, `HEIGHT`, `RADIUS` and `PEN_WIDTH` by the same factor.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something:

```
from turtle import *
ht() # Hides turtle
w,h,n = 130,200,6 # Set the width,height & amount of rectangles
for _ in range(n):
    pu()
    fd(h//2) # Note the double slashes to avoid error
    pd()
    for f in [w//2,h,w,h,w//2]:
        rt(90)
        fd(f)
    pu()
    rt(90)
    fd(h//2)
    rt(180-180//n)
```

[image]